# true boolean property turn into false when recived in the server side

Tags: java, .net, jaxb, jersey

I have a client-side which is implemented with Jersey and JAXB, I want to send a pojo class to .Net API Server side (Rest web service). when I set a boolean property to true and send it to the server, the boolean is turned to false.

The code below is used in client-side to call an API on .Net server side

```
    public String boolTest() {

        try {


          GetBoolTest getBoolTest = new GetBoolTest(true);


            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
            WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
            ClientResponse response = null;


            response = service.path("Test")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8-")
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, getBoolTest);

            GetBoolTestResponse getBoolTestResponse = null;



            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                getBoolTestResponse = response.getEntity(GetBoolTestResponse.class);
                System.out.println(getBoolTestResponse.toString());

            }else{
                switch (response.getStatus()) {
                    case 400:
                        throw new Exception("BadRequestException:: malFormed message : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 401:
                        throw new Exception("NotAuthorizedException:: Authorized failure : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 403:
                        throw new Exception("forbiddenException:: not permitted to access : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 404:
                        throw new Exception("NotFoundException:: could not find resource : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 405:
                        throw new Exception("NotAllowedException:: HTTP method not supported : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 406:
                        throw new Exception("NotAcceptableException:: client media type not supported : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 415:
                        throw new Exception("NotSupportedException::  client posted media not supported : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 500:
                        throw new Exception("InternalServerErrorException:: General Server Error : " + response.getStatus());
                    case 503:
                        throw new Exception("ServiceUnAvailableException:: server is temporarily unavailable or busy : " + response.getStatus());
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
                }
            }


            return String.valueOf(getBoolTestResponse);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "1800";
        }
    }
```

Pojo Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GetBoolTest {

    protected Boolean  isValue;


    public GetBoolTest() {
    }

    public GetBoolTest(Boolean isValue) {
        this.isValue = isValue;
    }

    public Boolean getIsValue() {
        return isValue;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setIsValue(Boolean isValue) {
        this.isValue = isValue;
    }
}
```

Response Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GetBoolTestResponse {



    protected boolean isValue;



    public boolean getIsValue() {
        return isValue;
    }

    public void setIsValue(boolean value) {
        this.isValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GetBoolTestResponse{" +
                "getIsValue=" + isValue +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the log output:

```
1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://**.**.***.***:***/api/Test/Test
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > Accept: application/json
{"value":"true"}
1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
1 < Date: Mon, 24 Apr 2023 08:03:49 GMT
1 < X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
1 < 
{"value":false,"formatters":[],"contentTypes":[],"declaredType":null,"statusCode":200}
GetBoolTestResponse{value=false}
```

I tried many ways, there is no problem testing with post man! also tried with many versions jersey 1.x and 2.x but still have this issue.

Comment: Instead of using Boolean  isValue; use Boolean  value and ordinary getValue, setValue. It might be naming conventions. Also, for diagnosis make value public and remove the get/set.

Comment: @JohnWilliams did what you said but still have problem

Comment: Then we need much more code. Enough code and example xml to simulate and fix.

Comment: @JohnWilliams i just edit the question with full code that i used. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use `setValue()` as the name of the setter function. The lookup from JSON property is done using the name of the setter for deserialization and the name of the getter for the serialization.

Comment: In java the default value for a boolean is false. I suspect that a field with a matching name is not being returned so it is never set. We need to establish whether the value is being returned by the API. Change .post(ClientResponse.class, getBoolTest) to .post(String.class, getBoolTest) and GetBoolTestResponse getBoolTestResponse to String getBoolTestResponse and see what raw value prints out. I suspect that the boolean field is misnamed.